# When importing data with 'vminsert' in 'victoriametrics' cluster mode, a 204 code is returned

Tags: victoriametrics

I have set up VictoriaMetrics cluster mode in Kubernetes.

```
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/vminsert-79955fd456-f6p5f   1/1     Running   0          2m15s
pod/vminsert-79955fd456-qgrlv   1/1     Running   0          2m12s
pod/vminsert-79955fd456-skc2x   1/1     Running   0          2m12s
pod/vmselect-698556d84c-7z9p7   1/1     Running   0          150m
pod/vmselect-698556d84c-8spgr   1/1     Running   0          150m
pod/vmselect-698556d84c-sp8n9   1/1     Running   0          150m
pod/vmstorage-0                 1/1     Running   0          151m
pod/vmstorage-1                 1/1     Running   0          150m
pod/vmstorage-2                 1/1     Running   0          150m
pod/vmstorage-3                 1/1     Running   0          150m
pod/vmstorage-4                 1/1     Running   0          149m

NAME                                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                      AGE
service/vminsert                   LoadBalancer   172.0.0.81     x.x.x.x   8480:30088/TCP,4242:32436/TCP   2m15s
service/vmselect                   LoadBalancer   172.0.0.79     y.y.y.y   8481:32473/TCP               150m
service/vmstorage                  ClusterIP      None             <none>           8482/TCP,8401/TCP,8400/TCP   151m
```

When calling the import API with 'vminsert', a 204 code is returned.
Referred API: https://docs.victoriametrics.com/url-examples.html#apiv1importprometheus

```
$ curl -d 'test{foo="bar"} 123' -X POST http://x.x.x.x:8480/insert/0/prometheus/api/v1/import/prometheus -u admin -v
Enter host password for user 'admin':
* About to connect() to x.x.x.x port 8480 (#0)
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* Connected to x.x.x.x (x.x.x.x) port 8480 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /insert/0/prometheus/api/v1/import/prometheus HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: x.x.x.x:8480
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 19
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 19 out of 19 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< X-Server-Hostname: vminsert-79955fd456-skc2x
< Date: Wed, 22 Feb 2023 07:55:23 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host x.x.x.x left intact
```

Any idea on what can cause it?

As I can see that the data is not being queried, it seems that the data was not written. I would like to know how to write the data.

Comment: It looks like VictoriaMetrics always returns 204, to find out if there was a problem you have to check the server-side logs (see https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/2420)

Answer (score 2):

VictoriaMetrics has some delay time when the inserted data became available for queries and to check that the data is present you can also send curl query like:

```
curl http://localhost:8481/select/0/prometheus/api/v1/export -d 'match={foo="bar"}'
```

See https://docs.victoriametrics.com/url-examples.html#apiv1export